least privilege for function app config write
Which is the azure built-in role to use for least privilege that enables users to write to function app config?
I think the required action is: Microsoft.Web/sites/config/write
I checked this site and the only built in role containing this action was "Logic Apps Standard Developer"?
I have tried "Website Contributor" but no luck:


I think the role you're after is Website Contributor, although I'm struggling to find hard documentation to support that there isn't a less privileged role. The closest I can find are these MS learn docs around the
RBAC permissions required to access Kudu.

Thanks for the answer but I tried that role and it didn't work - it doesn't have the required action.
